# mtrecorder and spirecorder, what are they?

Tags: macos, daemons

I've run a EtreCheck on my OS X 10.10.3 just now and I got some error messages.

```
Problem System Launch Daemons:
    [failed]    com.apple.mtrecorder.plist

Launch Daemons:
    [failed]    com.apple.spirecorder.plist
```

I did some research from Google but seems I cannot find some useful information. I am a little bit worry about the system since these two components come from Apple.

[image]

The content of com.apple.spirecorder.plist is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>EnableTransactions</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PathState</key>
        <dict>
            <key>/var/db/.spirecorder.forcedenable</key>
            <true/>
            <key>/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spirecorder.enable</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.apple.spirecorder</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/libexec/spirecorder</string>
        <string>-count</string>
        <string>50000</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Umask</key>
    <integer>18</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The content of com.apple.mtrecorder.plist is:

```
Yang$ plutil -convert xml1 -o - /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mtrecorder.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>EnableTransactions</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PathState</key>
        <dict>
            <key>/var/db/.mtrecorder.forcedenable</key>
            <true/>
            <key>/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mtrecorder.enable</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.apple.mtrecorder</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/libexec/mtrecorder</string>
    </array>
    <key>Umask</key>
    <integer>18</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And both `/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/` and `/usr/local/libexec` folders are not exists on my Mac.

By the way I found `com.apple.spirecorder.plist` in another LaunchDaemons folder which includes only one file, I removed it, rebooted and no problem with it. Now EtreCheck shows only one error with mtrecorder, I am not sure whether I am going to remove it since it comes with lots of Apple daemons in the same folder.

Comment: Were you perhaps running a beta version of Yosemite that you then upgraded to the final version?

Comment: Nope, this is a clean install of 10.10.3, I swiped the disk and reinstalled.

Comment: Neither of these files exist on my install of 10.10.3. And everyone discussing them on Google seems to be reporting the same as yourself, that launchd is trying to launch them and failing. Could you update the question with the content of these files? You should find them in /System/Library/LaunchAgents or /System/Library/LaunchDaemons.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan, If you cannot see these files exists in your /System/Library/LaunchDaemons directories, does it mean I can simply remove them? I removed com.apple.spirecorder.plist with no problem, because it was located in a Daemon folder with only one file exist. I am no sure whether I am going to throw away mtrecorder.plist as well.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. These files are binary plists so cat won't actually show you the exact content. You can use `plutil -convert xml1 -o - /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mtrecorder.plist` to show the full content.

Comment: The mention of "/var/mobile" is interesting because that doesn't exist in OS X as far as I know. I think that's just an iOS folder. This might be another example of iOS specific code that has somehow been left in OS X by mistake like the DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit stuff mentioned in http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/161516/4007. I think you are safe to remove that mtrecorder file too.

Comment: You can run `pkgutil --file-info /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mtrecorder.plist` to find out where that file came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these plist files appear to be part of the iOS operating system, that have been left in OS X by accident due to the shared nature of their development.

The reason you are seeing errors in EtreCheck for these files is that the plist files are telling the launchd process to run executables that don't actually exist on Macs, but only on iOS devices. And even then perhaps only on devices that are used for development.

I think you are safe to remove both files (although I would keep a copy of them somewhere), firstly because they are failing to launch anyway, and secondly because only seem to relate to components of the iOS operating system.