# Am I being hacked?

Tags: macos, console, hacking

I've had several devices wiped because of a very clever/annoying person who won't leave me alone (electronically).

I'm starting to become suspicious of my brand new Macbook Pro 13" purchased from Apple 2 weeks ago, Avast blocks a virus from my Dropbox around 30 times a day, therefore i've removed said application now.

Here is the Console log, can anyone reassure/warn me? Thanks very much.. (apologies for the length of the report, I've removed most dupilcations, it actually goes on for around 250 pages, just from today!)

[image: console screengrab 1]
[image: console screengrab 2]

Comment: Which log entry(ies) make(s) you suspicious?

Comment: Were these "devices" that were wiped iOS or Android?

Comment: It's preferable to paste the actual log, rather than screenshots of the log which can't be searched or indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer...  no.   You're likely just fine.   The error message you are seeing is "common"... you can read more about it on this other post:

[Strange message in console about _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155458/strange-message-in-console-about-dirtyjetsammemorylimit-key)

The post describes in detail the error you are seeing and what it means.

Comment: I'll try and paste again.... This happened while I was asleep and wifi was turned off. 05/09/2015 22:16:14.000 kernel[0]: IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe
05/09/2015 22:16:14.000 kernel[0]: IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe ProductID - 0x8290 FirmwareVersion - 0x0090
05/09/2015 22:16:14.000 kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- completed -- result = TRUE -- 0x3000 ****
05/09/2015 22:16:14.000 kernel[0]: **** [BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- Completed (matched on Device) -- 0x3000 ****
05/09/2015 22:16:14.000 kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController][staticBluetoo

Comment: I'm suspicious of the Generating screengrabs of desktop messages and also of the AppleCamIn.                                                                       05/09/2015 22:18:31.818 coreaudiod[297]: 2015-09-05 10:18:31.817899 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopping to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
05/09/2015 22:18:32.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
05/09/2015 22:18:32.892 WindowServer[222]: device_generate_desktop_screenshot: authw 0x7fc9e0024bc0(2000), shield 0x7fc9db4744a0(2001)

Comment: 05/09/2015 22:18:32.908 WindowServer[222]: device_generate_lock_screen_screenshot: authw 0x7fc9e0024bc0(2000)[0, 0, 1280, 800] shield 0x7fc9db4744a0(2001), dev [1280,800]
05/09/2015 22:18:46.825 discoveryd[75]: Basic BTMMServer Sleep offload failed. Start deregistering
05/09/2015 22:18:46.827 airportd[51]: _configureScanOffloadParameters: 
05/09/2015 22:18:49.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000280
05/09/2015 22:18:50.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 8561.957056: wl0: leaveModulePoweredForOffloads: Wi-Fi will stay on.

Comment: @Klanomath: The Bluetooth, AppleCamIn and Screengrabs of Desktop messages mainly... Especially as I was asleep while this was happening and my wifi was switched off.

Comment: @RedEagle2000: A mixture of both Apple, Android and Windows devices! My wallet is seriously light these days...

Comment: @grgarside: Apologies for the screen grab, I originally tried to copy and paste however it thought I was spamming and because i'm new it would only allow me to attach two pictures...

Thanks everyone!